# Sylius upload product image

Tags: symfony, nginx, upload, sylius

I have a problem on sylius while creating a product. Sylius is installed on an Nginx server. I tried to create the media/image folder in the web directory but this don't work. Changing permissions or owner don't work either.

I'm on an Nginx server and I've installed the Sylius/Sylius package (not the sandbox).

Visually I have the well sized thumbnail (no errors) but nothing in it.

I'm out of ideas, and you ? (:

Comment: Check app/error.log and nginx error logs.

Comment: I have no app/logs/error.log file but in the app/logs/dev.log I only found all database logs when I :
tail -fn 5 dev.log | grep image

In ngix I have a 
[error] 22260#0: *14570 open() "path/to/sylius/web/bundles/syliusweb/img/error.svg" failed (2: No such file or directory)
It doesn't seems related

Comment: What about apache error.log?